# Is it possible to declare variables within a certain interval within Java

Tags: java, class, variables, parameters

Say I have declared a class with a variable, alpha, of type double float. Is it in any way possible to define alpha within a certain interval, say  (1, 3).

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.... First thing you can learn!

Comment: @Jlatmer it is very confusing that you accept an edit to remove the Javascript tag, but then change the language in the title to Javascript. Please be consistent.

Comment: From the content of your question, I guess you're talking about Java. Consider editing your question.

Comment: So what this question is about JS or Java?

Comment: The question refers to Java

Answer (score 0):

You can't. However if really needed you could create your own Class:

```
public class FloatWithinInterval {
    public static final int LOWER_BOUND = 1;
    public static final int UPPER_BOUND = 3;
    public final float value;

    public FloatWithinInterval(float value) {
        if(value < LOWER_BOUND || value > UPPER_BOUND) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); //Or a custom exception
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Note that thanks to the `final` keyword, your value is immutable.

Then your field would be declared as

```
FloatWithinInterval alpha;
```

And to initialise it, instead of

```
alpha = 2.0f;
```

You would have to write

```
alpha = new FloatWithinInterval(2.0f);
```

And you can access your value with `alpha.value`